# How publish java project in github?

Tags: java, git, github

If I have a Java web project on github, is it possible to create a [github page](https://pages.github.com/) from the source files? Something like [this](http://dperrymorrow.github.io/example-backbone-app/) (How is posible add several javascript libraries to main html?).

Comment: **Github page can only host static web-site.** So you can't set up a servlet container like Tomcat, Jetty or Glassfish. Maybe you can use java applet in a github page... (but applet are evils). What technologies do you use ?

Comment: Its not a good idea to compare apples and oranges, or in this case a compiled language such as Java and an interpreted language such as Javascript. You could deploy your application on a Java-enabled cloud service such as Google Apps or Openshift if you can't setup your own server environment as suggested.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use GitHub.

Comment: I use AngularJs + Spring MVC + MongoDB

Comment: @fredyjimenezrendon, so... is this a *Java* application or a *JavaScript* application? Those two things are entirely unrelated.

Comment: @Chris Is a Java application. Maybe, is not posible because we need a application server. In this case I want to know how its posible add several js libraries to main html file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run your Java application on GitHub. For this purpose you need an application server, for example [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/), [Glassfish](https://glassfish.java.net/), or [Wildfly](http://www.wildfly.org/). Github gives you the opportunity to show only HTML pages with JavaScript.

Comment: there are a cloud service to deploy a java app in github?